# tree traversal in lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp

I'm trying to traverse a tree in lisp and print out all the parent-child relations. 
Here is my input: (5 (3 (4 (1)) (g) (9 (6))) (n (8 (0)) (q) (7) (b (f (c (a))))))
I'm trying to get it to print out something along the lines of:

```
5>3

5>n

3>4

3>g

3>9

4>1

9>6

n>8

n>q

n>7

n>b

8>0

b>f

f>c

c>a
```

my current code is below:

```
(defun par-child-print (l)
    (print l)
    (cond ((not (null (caadr l))) 
    (print "start")
    (print (car l)) 
    (print ">") 
    (print (caadr l)) 
    (print "end")
    (cond ((not (atom (car l))) (when (not (eq (car l) NIL)) (par-child-print (car l)))));

    (when (not (eq (cdr l) NIL)) (par-child-print (cdr l)))

    )
(t 
)));
```

The problem is that my output only sometimes prints the parent (and also it doesnt make it through the whole tree). Any ideas?

I also have this that makes it through the whole tree, but doesn't even attempt to keep track of parents:

```
(defun atom-print (l)
(print l)
(cond ((atom l) (print l));
(t 
(when (not (eq (car l) NIL)) (atom-print (car l)))
(when (not (eq (cdr l) NIL)) (atom-print (cdr l)))


)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each list in the tree consists of two parts, a name and a list of children. Those are the same as the `CAR` and the `CDR` of the list, but for semantic reasons you could start by defining aliases for them:

```
(defun name (tree) (car tree))
(defun children (tree) (cdr tree))
```

These abstract away the details of how the tree is implemented. Then, given a tree you want to do two things:

1. Print a line per child with the parents name and the childs name. This could be done like this:

   ```
   (dolist (child (children tree))
     (format t "~&~a > ~a" (name tree) (name child)))
   ```
2. Print each child the same way. This is done by calling the function recursively on them:

   ```
   (dolist (child (children tree))
     (print-tree child))
   ```

So the whole function would look like this:

```
(defun print-tree (tree)
  (dolist (child (children tree))
    (format t "~&~a > ~a" (name tree) (name child)))
  (dolist (child (children tree))
    (print-tree child)))

(print-tree '(5 (3 (4 (1)) (g) (9 (6))) (n (8 (0)) (q) (7) (b (f (c (a)))))))
; 5 > 3
; 5 > N
; 3 > 4
; 3 > G
; 3 > 9
; 4 > 1
; 9 > 6
; N > 8
; N > Q
; N > 7
; N > B
; 8 > 0
; B > F
; F > C
; C > A
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with [jkiiski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37018908/821010): it works on the given input, but only because each `child` has `children` of its own.  Here's a variant on that answer that has the same behaviour on the sample input, but that also works on other trees.

```lisp
(defun print-tree (tree)
  (dolist (child (cdr tree))
    (format t "~&~a > ~a" (car tree) (if (consp child)
                                         (car child)
                                       child)))
  (dolist (child (cdr tree))
    (if (consp child)
        (print-tree child))))


(print-tree '(A (B (C 1 2 3) 4)))
A > B
B > C
B > 4
C > 1
C > 2
C > 3
```